# make dist with qmake

Tags: qt, qt5, qmake

I have a Qt project with qmake.

After I generate the makefile, if I run `make dist`, the generated tarball will contain a bunch of .pri and .conf files that aren't part of my project but come from Qt. Is there a way to exclude these?

In any case shipping them with my sources is useless because they aren't sufficient to compile it.